# Array adapter getview shows only last value using SOAP for Android

Tags: java, android, listview, soap, android-arrayadapter

I am new to android,i am implementing custom listview using array adapter,in my arraylist i am having 10 different values but while i setting this values to listview it displaying only the last view.i am very confusing please clear my doubt

Here is my array adapter

```js
package com.example.pfdv2;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ProductAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Product> {
 
 Context context; 
    int layoutResourceId;    
    Product data[] = null;
    
    private static final String TAG = "CustomAdapter";
    private static int convertViewCounter = 0;
    
    
 public ProductAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId,Product[] data) {

  super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;
 }
 
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        ProductHolder holder = null;
        
        if(row == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
            
            holder = new ProductHolder();
            holder.txtvCode = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.txtvCode);
            holder.txtvBrand = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.txtvBrand);
            holder.txtvQuantity = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.txtvQuantity);
            holder.txtvName = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.txtvName);
            holder.txtvPriceC = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.txtvPriceC);
            holder.txtvPriceC2 = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.txtvPriceC2);
            holder.txtvPointsC = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.txtvPointsC);
         //   holder.txtvPointsCC = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.txtvPointsCC);
            holder.txtvPriceU = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.txtvPriceU);
            holder.txtvPriceU2 = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.txtvPriceU2);
            holder.txtvPointsU = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.txtvPointsU);
        //    holder.txtvPointsUU = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.txtvPointsUU);
            
            row.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
        {
            holder = (ProductHolder)row.getTag();
        }
        
        Product product = data[position];
       
        holder.txtvCode.setText(Product.getProductID());
        
        holder.txtvBrand.setText(Product.getProductType());
        
        holder.txtvQuantity.setText(Product.BrandID());
        
        holder.txtvName.setText(Product.getProductName());
        
        double j = Product.getCartonPrice();
  String jresult = new Double(j).toString();
        holder.txtvPriceC.setText(jresult);
        
        double k = Product.getCartonPoints();
  String kresult = new Double(k).toString();
        holder.txtvPriceC2.setText(kresult);
        
        double l = Product.getCTNAvail();
  String lresult = new Double(l).toString();
        holder.txtvPointsC.setText(lresult);
        
     //   holder.txtvPointsCC.setText(product.get());
      
        double m = Product.getUnitPrice();
  String mresult = new Double(m).toString();
        holder.txtvPriceU.setText(mresult);
        
        double n = Product.getUnitPoints();
  String nresult = new Double(n).toString();
        holder.txtvPriceU2.setText(nresult);
        
        double o = Product.getUnitAvail();
  String oresult = new Double(o).toString();
        holder.txtvPointsU.setText(oresult);
       // holder.txtvPointsUU.setText(product.getUnitAvail());
         
        return row;
    }
    
    static class ProductHolder
    {
        ImageView imgIcon;
        TextView txtvCode,txtvBrand,txtvQuantity,txtvName,txtvPriceC,txtvPriceC2,txtvPointsC,
        txtvPointsCC,txtvPriceU,txtvPriceU2,txtvPointsU,txtvPointsUU;
    }
}
```

Here is how i passing from my activity

```js
ackage com.example.pfdv2;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;

import com.example.pfdv2.ProductAdapter.ProductHolder;

import android.R.array;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;

 public class Page_ListRowP extends ListActivity {

  private static final String ProductAdapter = null;
  private TextView text;
  private TextView  textVitems,txtProductName,txtBrandID,txtProductID,txtProductType,txtCartonP,txtCPoints, txtUAvail, txtUPrice, txtCTNA, txtUPoints;
  private TextView quantity,statusTV1;
  Button btn;
  private List<String> listValues;
  String name;
  int t=WsSearch.total;
     Boolean SearchStatus = WsSearch.SearchStatus;
  
     ListView lstClientes = null;
     
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setTitle(R.string.Search);
   setContentView(R.layout.page_list);
   
   ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
   actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);  
   ColorDrawable colorDrawable = new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("lightgray"));
      getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(colorDrawable);
   
      
      text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mainText);
            
   Product product_data[] = new Product[]
              {
      new Product()
              };

      ProductAdapter adapter = new ProductAdapter(this, 
     R.layout.row_products, product_data);
   
   setListAdapter(adapter);
           

        
  }
```

It is showing data but only the last part. How I can show the all values..

Thankssssss

Answer (score 0):

It looks your product_data array has only one item. It will display only one data as listitem. What is it you are trying you achieve?

Comment: I want to display a list of products. Each product has different values. Finally I can see all the values for one product... the last one. This list will change always depending of the search of the user. I don't know how to show the list @user3128485